# How to count number of rows in data.table using same condition on multiple columns in R

Tags: r, data.table

If I have the below data table in R

```
dt <- data.table(x = c("No", "No", "Yes")
              ,  y = c("No", "Yes", "Yes")
              ,  z = c("No", "No", "No")
              ,  q = c("Hi", "Where, "When")
              ,  AA = c(1, 1,1)
              ,  ID = c(999, 789, 567)
              , bop = c(2345, 2222,2222))
```

and I want to get the count of **"No"** in each variable(x, y, z) in below format

```
Variable Type Count

 x     No      2

 y     No     1

 z     No     3
```

I am not able to pass the same filter to  the columns I want. I can only pass filter to one column

```
dt[, .(.N), by = .(x,y,z)]
```

Comment: `colSums(as.matrix(dt[, x:z]) == "No")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `melt` to reshape into 'long' format, and then do a group by 'variable' (i.e. the column name column), get the number of 'No' by `sum`ming the logical vector (`value == 'No'`)

```
library(data.table)
melt(dt, id.var = 'q')[, .(Type = 'No', Count = sum(value == 'No')), .(variable)]
#   variable Type Count
#1:        x   No     2
#2:        y   No     1
#3:        z   No     3
```

---

For the new example

```
melt(dt[, .(x, y, z)], measure = c('x', 'y', 'z'))[, 
   .(Type = 'No', Count = sum(value == 'No')), .(variable)]
#    variable Type Count
#1:        x   No     2
#2:        y   No     1
#3:        z   No     3
```

Or specify the logical condition in `i` and use  `.N`

```
melt(dt[, .(x, y, z)], measure = c('x', 'y', 'z'))[value == 'No',
       .(Type = first(value), Count = .N), variable]
#   variable Type Count
#1:        x   No     2
#2:        y   No     1
#3:        z   No     3
```

---

Or without `melt`ing we can loop over the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`), create a logical vector and reduce the `list` to a single vector with `Reduce`

```
dt[, .(variable = names(.SD), Type = 'No', 
     Count = Reduce(`+`, lapply(.SD, `==`, 'No'))), .SDcols = x:z]
#  variable Type Count
#1:        x   No     3
#2:        y   No     2
#3:        z   No     1
```

Or using `rowSums`

```
dt[, .(Variable = names(.SD), Type = 'No',
        Count = rowSums(.SD == 'No')), .SDcols = x:z]
```

---

In the OP's code, the grouping columns were taken as 'x', 'y', 'z'. Then, if we do `.N`, it is looking for the number of rows for each unique set of values across those columns and this will be 1 for each case because there is only 1 row for `No No No` or `No Yes No` or `Yes Yes No`

Comment: The count column in the number of "No' in each variable and not "q"

Comment: It is why i counted with `sum(value == 'No')`

Comment: What if I don't have variable 'q'?

Comment: @Deb Please update your question.  I answered the question with the input example

Comment: I updated my question. Actually in real data there are many columns and I want the count for few of them . A single filter needs to be applied to all of them.

Comment: Thank you so munch @akrun! ! I was just wondering why can't this be handled by a .N

Comment: @Deb  With `melt` and `filter`ed data, you can use `.N`, only thing is that it should be in `i`

Comment: one last query. What if there are duplicate variable names , like "x" repeating 5 times. Then the 3rd and 4th method will give unique row for each value of "x". How to group "x" to one row in final output? @akrun

Comment: @Deb `duplicate` names are not recommended in data.frame or data.table as it can create issues.   You can change the column names with `setnames(dt, make.unique(names(dt)))`.  Which will add a suffix `.1`, `.2` etc for each duplicate column name